# How to add a button at the end of each node in a tree region in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I have a tree region in oracle apex which shows parents and children in a tree structure. I want to display a + button at the end of each node. On clicking this button i need to open a pop up which will allow the users to add a node under the selected parent. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to tree region attributes page and create a **link** which opens page in *this* application - a page you'll use to insert information you're interested in.

I don't think that you can create a *plus button* which will do that; at least, not with built-in Apex capabilities.